# facebook share button not picking the og:image as the default selected image

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I have used og:image tag with my facebook share button.
It is not picking the og:image as default selected image, whereas that is the same one as being shown in facebook debugger.

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: could it be becoz of the fact that it does not comply to the image size characteristics ? But if this is the case then shouldnt it be not shown on debugger as well ??

Comment: Did you accidentally include an og:url tag pointing to a different URL or a canonical meta tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter/debugger has an issue/bug.  It will display the image as if it passed muster.  However, it won't be displayed correctly in the shared news feed. I've seen this time and time again.

Comment: Most likely cause of that being an image below 50x50 resolution, or having one side more than 3 times larger than the other

Answer (score 4):

It's possible a different image is being cached.  I've read that if you review the page with Facebook URL Linter, it will reload the thumbnail images currently in the cache.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: i have checked the cached image .. i have mentioned that in the comment as well..